# Where to go to purchase parts for XY Plotter

Tags: stepper-motor, motion, actuator

I am trying to build a 2ft square an XY Plotter. I have seen three designs so far: 1)Rack and Pinion 2)Threaded Screw 3) belt-driven. all these use a stepper motor to drive the system.

Each one has their obvious pros and cons but correct me if i am wrong, i believe the rack and pinion system is the most sturdy and easiest to put together.

I googled for Rack and pinion but all i get is industrial websites. Is there any place that sells cheaper rack and pinion sets for hobbyists? The payload of the XY Table is an eletro-magnet that isn't extremely heavy (maybe a half kilogram at most).

So obviously the motor must be strong enough to move anothe rack which will be significantly heavier than the payload.

This is my first real robotics project so i am new to all this.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out pololu.com and sparkfun.com

Each of the motors you will find will have a torque rating which indicates how much torque they can produce. Stepper motors require stepper motor drivers to operate. The drivers usually take an input voltage pulse of 5 volts, and will then move the stepper motor attached to it 1 step. 
[image: stepper motor driver picture from pololu]
This is the stepper driver I just used for a project where I used the stepper setup to drive my little 5 lbs robot around on a ping pong table. I used this with a 68 oz.in stepper motor from sparkfun and an Arduino.

I imagine for a rack and pinion setup you would have to do some math to determine how far 1 step of the motor would move the tray based on the diameters of the gears and the degrees traveled by one step of the motor. Stepper motors have a paramater, steps per revolution, that specifies how much rotation happens for one step. There is a thing called microstepping which allows you to turn a stepper motor less than this rating.